# Cypress: How to count number of buttons

Tags: javascript, button, cypress, end-to-end

Hi I want to count the number of  buttons inside a specific tag
How can I print the sum of buttons?

I tried

```
cy.log(cy.get('dropdown').find('button').count())
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length by using .[its](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/its.html#Syntax):

```
cy.get('dropdown').find('button').its('length').should('eq', 4)
```

Or, You can also get the length like:

```
cy.get('dropdown').find('button').its('length').then((len) => {
    cy.log('No. of buttons are: ' + len)
})
```

Comment: Thanks it worked✌ can you explain what you did in the second answer?

Comment: `.its` gets a property’s value on the previously yielded subject. Now to work with the value that was generated by it, we need to use `then` which enables you to work with the subject yielded from the previous command.

Comment: How can I save the length in a variable?

Comment: Inside then you can save the variable as `var buttonLen = len`, but its scope will be inside `then()`. If you want have a global scope write it outside of then something like `var buttonLen = 0` and update its value inside then.

Comment: I tried it and it doen't save the updated value in its internal scope when I print the var outside the scope it says it still has the initialized value (0)

Comment: You can post a diff question for this imo as this question was only asked to get and print the value of length.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the count with an alias

```
cy.get('dropdown').find('button').its('length').as('buttonCount')

... // more actions e.g add a button

cy.get('@buttonCount').then(previousCount => {
  cy.get('dropdown').find('button').its('length')
    .should('be.gt', previousCount)
})
```